# How to filter nusted list-object by value?

Tags: python, list, filtering

In NumPy, you can filter array data in an array by value, for example, like this:

```
L = [[str(j) + str (i) for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)] 
# [['00' '01' '02'] 
# ['10' '11' '12'] 
# ['20' '21' '22']]
```

To find out what value is in the 1st column of the row containing the value "22" in the third column , have to the following:

```
print(A1[A1[:,2] == '22', 3]) 
#['20']
```

How do I do this sort of filtering in a normal two -dimensional array llist-type?

Or is it necessary to transfer to NumPy?

Comment: Your list comprehension does not output the shown values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a list comprehension :

```
L = [[str(j) + str (i) for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)] 

[l[0] for l in L if l[2] == '22']
```

you are iterating over the rows filtering by column 3 (index 2) and keeping the element from the first column (index 0)

output:

```
['20']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is imperative that you convert you nested list to a numpy array.

You can easily perform the asked operations as shown in the code below

```
L = [[2, 1, 0], [12, 10, 11], [21, 22, 20]]

L = [sorted(l) for l in L]

if(L[2][2]==22):
    print(L[2][0])
```